# implode breaks Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I'm making an Ajax call which will first check to see if that post ID has already been voted on.

Currently I'm just working on the PHP to first get the post id's, if it is empty set it or if it is not empty to append the ID.

**Question here:** Except when I use the implode or explode method it does not seem to make a call back to the javascript. Although if I was to refresh the page it does register the vote.

This is the PHP file. For `user Id` I've just set it to my admin id to start with.

```
function my_user_vote() {

    $user_id = 1;
    $pageVoted = $_REQUEST["post_id"];

    $currentPosts = get_user_meta($user_id, 'pages_voted_on');

    if (empty($currentPosts)) {
        // Empty create single array
        $postsVotedOn[] = $pageVoted;
    } else {
        $postsVotedOn = explode('|', $currentPosts);
        $postsVotedOn[] = $pageVoted;
    }
    $boo = implode("|", $pageVoted);

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'pages_voted_on', $boo);


   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "my_user_vote_nonce")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
   }   

   $vote_count = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", true);
   $vote_count = ($vote_count == '') ? 0 : $vote_count;
   $new_vote_count = $vote_count + 1;

   $vote = update_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", $new_vote_count);

   if($vote === false) {
      $result['type'] = "error";
      $result['vote_count'] = $vote_count;
   }
   else {
      $result['type'] = "success";
      $result['vote_count'] = $new_vote_count;
   }

   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      $result = json_encode($result);
      echo $result;
   }
   else {
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
   }


   die();

}
```

This is the javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

   jQuery(".user_vote").click( function() {
      post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id")
      nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               jQuery(".vote_counter").html("Votes: " + response.vote_count);

               jQuery(".voteUpButton").html('<div class="button btnGreen">Thank you!</div>');
               alert("Cooommmon");
               console.log(response.vote_count);
            }
            else {
               alert("Your vote could not be added")
            }
         }
      })   

   })

})
```

Comment: Can I ask why I was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test with your code, and found a couple of issues that throw errors:

**1.** This line:

`$currentPosts = get_user_meta($user_id, 'pages_voted_on');`

should be

`$currentPosts = get_user_meta($user_id, 'pages_voted_on', true);`

**2.** And I believe this line:

`$boo = implode("|", $pageVoted);`

should be

`$boo = implode("|", $postsVotedOn);`

Explanation:

1. Without the `true` argument `get_user_meta` returns an array. And you can't `explode` an array.
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta
2. `$pageVoted` is the id of the page to add, while `$postsVotedOn` is the actual list you want it appended to.

Comment: Oh my lord, the missing true was it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :) The same thing is true (no pun indented) for all the get_*_meta functions.